# Flutter user generated deep links

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to create user generated dynamic links? Like how share button works in Facebook or instagram.I know of firebase dynamic links but you've to manually create the dynamic links. I want the user to generate it.

The workflow being like this.
To share a post.The post page contains userId and postId.I want to share both postId and userId and image if possible.
A post in the flutter app. ====> users clicks on share post button.===> Opens a dialog with options(copy link or share link to other apps like WhatsApp or Instagram ).===> Selects instagram from options and app deep link is shared.The deep link when clicked from instagram==> redirects to the post in the flutter app.